# OpenGL Light Scattering: FBO and Framebuffer blending

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

I am trying to create the Light Scattering effect using OpenGL.
I am following this [tutorial](http://fabiensanglard.net/lightScattering/).

At some point it says:

> Switch to Orthogonal projection and blend the FBO with the framebuffer, activating the shader in order to generate the "God's ray" effect .

I don't understand what's the meaning of "blend the FBO with the Framebuffer". I looked for this "Blending" and I noticed that's a OpenGL pipeline step.

I was thinking that I should use the function glEnablei(GL_BLEND, fbo), but I don't know where I should call it.

To draw the mesh (the scene has one mesh and one light source) I use glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, n_of_verteces).

Can someone help me?

Comment: I do not think you want `glEnablei (GL_BLEND, fbo)`, that's gibberish unless `fbo` is the index of a single draw buffer (FBO attachment). Generally `fbo` would be the name of an FBO ;)

This is basic multi-pass rendering, and the general procedure is to draw into a texture attachment and then on a second pass, stretch that texture over the viewport with blending setup. _To be honest_, I don't understand the meaning of "blend the FBO with the Framebuffer" either =P It's a single image attached to the FBO that's of interest here; some parts of an FBO (_e.g._ depth) blending is meaningless for.

Answer (score 3):

Ugh, the instructions you cited are written unneccessarily confusing. What it asks you to do is take the texture you've rendered your god rays to (using the FBO) and draw it on top what's in the main (non-FBO) frame buffer using a single, full viewport textured quad. And the instruction to "blend it" is asking you to enable blending (everything drawn thereafter will blend with what's been drawn in the steps before, including other blended stuff) and choose an appropriate blending function; (GL_ONE, GL_ONE) would be the obvious one for lighting effect stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I feel a bit noob XD

In my work I have two shaders couple of shaders:
The ones to draw the mesh normally (PRE)
The ones with the fragment shader to create the God ray effect (POST).

So what I should do is:

1) Draw the mesh black in the FBO, using PRE-shaders

2) Draw the God Ray in the FBO, blending, using POST-shaders, 

3) swap to the normal framebuffer

4) Draw the mesh normally

5) Draw the FBO